# which pipeline used for distributed System in CNTK?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, pipeline, cntk

I'm new in Microsoft CNTK

Google Tensorflow used grpc for communicating with each machine ,
but i don't know which pipeline used for distributed System in CNTK, Can you let me know?

and Could you give me some reference or site about example of multi machines , multi GPU?
i already have been to this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines) , but i cannot find multi machine information or code.

THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has changed over various versions but the most current information is that the binary releases under Linux and GPU are built with Nvidia's NCCL 2 library (since version 2.3) and under Windows they are built with MS-MPI. Other versions are built with OpenMPI.

The page you are linking to has a lot of information especially in the sections 
about [the necessary changes to your Python script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines#2-configuring-parallel-training-in-cntk-in-python) (they are minimal) and [how to invoke it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines#42-running-parallel-training-with-python).